# Using the single verb "extinguish" in modern English

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I wonder if in the following context I can substitue the bold sentence with the further sentence of mine:

> In the 1980s, father-and-son scientists Luis and Walter Alvarez discovered in the geological record a distinct layer of iridium–an element found in abundance only in space that corresponds to the precise time the dinosaurs died. This suggests that a comet, asteroid or meteor impact event may **have caused the extinction of the dinosaurs**.

I need to know if the substitution of the above and below sentences would change the meaning of the paragraph or something like its formality degree or not.

> - ...**have extinguished the dinosaurs**.

I need to use a single verb to convey this message and dictionaries confirm that the verb "extinguish" can serve it right, but I doubt whether it is common in modrn English or not.

P.S. I've read the similar page on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current usage, **to extinguish** is used for fires, and **extinct** is used for species and volcanoes.

In the sense of volcanoes being no longer active or species no longer existing, the OED says of **extinct** (for this purpose): "in modern use it usually denotes a state without reference to the action from which this results."

So you have to say:

- "... may have made the dinosaurs **extinct**", or
- "... may have caused the **extinction** of the dinosaurs" (as in your quote)

But for a fire you have to use the verb:

- "The rain may have **extinguished** the fire"

A fire being extinct sounds antiquated.